# Как установить Android SDK для IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android-sdk, intellij-idea

Не могу установить Android SDK для IntelliJ IDEA, который я скачал с сайта https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html (sdk-tools-windows-3859397).

Инсталятора нигде не видно, при запуске экзешников открывается на секунду командная строка и всё, даже с помощью прав администратора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно никакого установщика. Просто распакуйте в какую то папку и в настройках проекта IDEA укажите путь до нее, в поле, где требуется указать путь до Android SDK

Comment: IDEA не "узнаёт" эту папку как папку с SDK. Там же на странице откуда   это скачено написано "If you do not need Android Studio, you can download the basic Android command line tools below. You can use the included sdkmanager to download other SDK packages", т.е. это не полный комплект. Из этого комплекта надо использовать sdkmanager чтобы скачать остальное. У обычного SDK структура каталогов немного другая - там их побольше должно быть.

Comment: вопрос актуален?

Answer (score 2):

Ставил я это все дело первый раз, так что насколько все правильно я не знаю. Напишу что я сделал чтобы заработало...

- Ставим jdk с версией 1.8. С версией 1.7 sdkmanager у меня работать не
  хотел.
- Распаковываем содержимое архива например в C:\AndroidSdk\tools. Если
  я все правильно понял, то папка tools обязательна.
- Создаем переменную среды ANDROID_HOME=C:\AndroidSdk
- Устанавливаем через sdkmanager пакеты. Я поставил следующие...

  1. *platforms;android-19* - версию выбираем нужную
  2. *build-tools;19.1.0* - не уверен что версия должна совпадать с platforms;android
  3. *platform-tools*
  4. *extras;android;m2repository* - без этого проект не соберется

Все теперь можно скармливать IntelliJ IDEA папку C:\AndroidSdk.

**PS:** Пока пытался ставить пробовал разные варианты и у меня не работало пока не поставил именно пакет *platforms;android-19*. После этого идея распознала папку C:\AndroidSdk как sdk. Возможно идеи нужен установленный хотя бы один sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Я сам новичок, но была такая же проблема. Установил JDK (Java Development Kit) проблема решилась. Также нужно внести путь к JDK в переменную среду Система -> дополнительные параметры системы-> Переменные среды

Comment: Да. Я это сделал, но проблема не исчезла.