# Подключить Android SDK к Intelli IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь установить Android SDK в Intelig IDEA community. 
Выполняю все по инструкции указанной на этом сайте: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/...velopment.html

1. Уже установлены: jdk-9.0.1, Intelig IDEA community.
2. Скачал Android SDK (не Android Studio) с этого сайта (ссылка для скачивания в самом конце страницы, под заголовком 
   Get just the command line tools): 
   https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
   Далее распаковал архив в эту папку: C:\android\AndroidSdk.
3. Просят запустить программу установки Android SDK Tools Setup. Не нашел этой программы в распакованном архиве
   и на сайте откуда скачал Android SDK. В других источниках, в которых объясняется как подключить Android SDK к 
   Intelig IDEA, просят запустить SDK manager. На том же сайте, где и скачал sdk, говорится что речь идет о файле sdkmanager.bat
   и в командной строке нужно указать необходимые пакеты для загрузки. Я ввел следующие данные в командной строке:
   sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26". Получил: 
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Мучаюсь уже второй день. Пожалуйста подскажите что я не так делаю.

Comment: Просто мне проще работать с помощью одних и тех же инструментов. И не хотелось бы иметь две ide когда можно обойтись одной. А к Intellig IDEA я уже привык.

Comment: Android Studio - это та же Inteleg IDEA Community с уже подключенным и настроенным Andriod SDK. Зачем мучатся два дня, когда можно просто скачать и установить за пять минут?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что если Intellig IDEA уже установлена, то при установке Android Studio просто подключится Android SDK к уже используемой на компьютере IDEA?

Comment: Нет, Android Studio установит ещё одну IDEA, свою.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь [Как установить Android SDK для IntelliJ IDEA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668145/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-android-sdk-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-intellij-idea?rq=1)

Comment: Спасибо,  Igor Kudryashov, смотрел. Так я и понял что нужно устанавливать недостающие пакеты через sdkmanager.bat, но с этим в результате и возникли проблемы описанные выше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72144/discussion-between-bakuard-and-igor-kudryashov).